# Regular expression(javascript) to extract a string preceded by some constant string

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

I am trying to extract a string which is preceded by some constant string, the example is as follows.

```
string ="deleteabc@bcd" 
match should be "abc@bcd"
or
string = "deletebcd@def"
match should be "bcd@def"
```

so as you can see i want to extract anything after the constant string "delete", 
please help, thanks in advance

Comment: you can use string.substring(string.indexOf('delete') + 'delete'.length)

Comment: In most other regex flavours you could use lookbehinds: (?<=delete).+ but javascript doesn't do them does it?

Comment: Why would you need look behind? Generally if you think you need it, think twice if just the pattern without it will do just as fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "deleteabc@bcd"
result = string.match(/^delete(.+)/)
console.log(result[1])
```

abc@bcd

Comment: this one is closest to what i wanted, though i must say Matt's answer is also pretty good, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove a prefix

```
function removePrefix(str, prefix) {
    if (str.search(prefix) === 0) {
        return str.substr(prefix.length);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```